# SetText in EditText Android error

Tags: android, android-edittext

I want to setText in EditView but it will error. I dont know why.

This is on OnCreate function.

```
name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.input_name);

String editname = String.valueOf(getName());
MessageTo.message(this,editname);

name.setText(editname);
```

The string i will set in EditText name.

```
public String getName(){
    int id = 1;
    String data=dbhandler.getName(id);

    return data;
}
```

If i remove this code from the OnCreate function

```
name.setText(editname);
```

It will have no error. The MessageTo.message code is where it pops a dialog of the String editname. It will show the String editname.

So i put back the code and change it into this code,

```
name.setText("testing");
```

But it still won't work.

I dont know why though. All other sources have EditText.setText("String") as how to setText in EditText but it won't work in my case.

LOGCAT ERROR:

```
09-20 21:00:36.677    1436-1436/? E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.organizer/com.organizer.ManageProfileActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Comment: What does the error from Logcat say?

Comment: i dont know how to identify the error

Comment: Not the problem but why are you calling `String.valueOf()` on a returned variable that is already a `String`? Also, what is `MessageTo`? That could be an issue. You only posted a small part of the logcat. Post the rest of the error so we can see where the exception is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `EditText` `name` appears to be null. In your `onCreate` method, make sure you are calling `setContentView(R.layout.YOUR_LAYOUT)` where the layout parameter is an XML layout containing your `EditText` with the ID `R.id.input_name`.

You assign it later on with

```
name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.input_name);
```

but if the layout does not contain this ID, `name` will be null, thus causing your error.

Comment: No problem! Consider marking this and any future answers that help you as "correct." It will help people down the road who stumble upon the same issue figure it out

Answer (score 0):

It is correct that you should be using the setText() method on the EditText.

Everything looks correct in terms of your codes, so I would suggest to check for the following things:

- Are you calling setText anywhere else?
- Is the id of your EditText correct (Is the id of your EditText input_name)
- Are you sure you are looking at the right activity.
- Are you initializing your name variable in the right scope? (Outside the onCreate Method)

Comment: no, only once for that EditText name. and yes, its the correct id name. yes on the right activity. No only in the OnCreate method.

Answer (score 0):

1. Declare the EditText in the xml file
2. Find the EditText in the activity
3. Set the text in the EditText

And If you check the docs for EditText, you'll find a setText() method. It takes in a String and a TextView.BufferType. For example:

```
EditText editText =     (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edit_text);
editText.setText("Google is your friend.", TextView.BufferType.EDITABLE);
```

Or 
Use +, the string concatenation operator:

```
 ed = (EditText) findViewById (R.id.box);
    int x = 10;
    ed.setText(""+x);
```

or

```
String.valueOf(int):
ed.setText(String.valueOf(x));
```